# OpenCV showing "Can't parse 'contours'. Input argument doesn't provide sequence protocol"

Tags: python, opencv

The initial code for CpenCV black line detection is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 160)
cap.set(4, 120)
c = 0

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    low_b = np.uint8([5,5,5])
    high_b = np.uint8([0,0,0])
    mask = cv2.inRange(frame, high_b, low_b)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, 1, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    if len(contours) > 0:
        c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        if M["m00"] !=0:
            cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
            cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
            print("CX : "+str(cx)+"  CY : "+str(cy))
            if cx >= 120:
                print("Left")
            if cx < 120 and cx > 40:
                print("On Track!!")
            if cx <= 40:
                print("Right")
            cv2.circle(frame,(cx,cy),5,(255,255,255),-1)

    cv2.drawContours(frame, c, -1, (0,255,0), 1)
    cv2.imshow("Mask",mask)
    cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):   # 1 is the time in ms
       break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For which I am getting the error as shown here:

```
> cv2.drawContours(frame, c, -1, (0,255,0), 1)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'drawContours'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'contours'. Input argument doesn't provide sequence protocol
>  - Can't parse 'contours'. Input argument doesn't provide sequence protocol
```

I tried changing the frame W and H.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cv2.drawContours(frame, [c], -1, (0,255,0), 1)
```

drawContours expects a list of contours.